# awkward array search and print response

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AuPy2W3X_sXDxdqXG4Zv-Lv9uYhGwTWH1na8qDnf0Ys/edit#gid=0).
In raw, there is an awkward array (no changing the format, I know it looks ugly but there's a reason. I color-coded this sample so you can see where each person's data starts and ends) I need the first and last name on raw matched to roster (a:b), and for the age to be parsed into the roster for the corresponding person, column c.

For example, because a6 and b6 on roster match raw c2 and c1, cell c6 on roster should be equal to raw c4, which is "7".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 FLATTEN(FILTER(raw!B1:D, raw!A1:A=A1)), 
 FLATTEN(FILTER(raw!B1:D, raw!A1:A=B1)),
 FLATTEN(FILTER(raw!B1:D, raw!A1:A=C1))},
 "where Col1 is not null", )
```

[image]